# Cannot use namespace 'TuiEditor' as a type

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, toast-ui-editor

I have searched the generic error I am getting ('Cannot use namespace x as a type.') and I can't seem to match my error up with others' examples.

I have an Ionic3/Angular6 application where I have the ngx-tui-editor npm package installed so I can have a markdown editor in my app.

Everything was working fine all morning. I was able to see the editor come up just fine, I could interact with it, get/set markdown content, etc. Then, after a random refresh as I was setting this all up into a form, I started getting the above error.

The thing is, the error is referencing this code block (middle line):

```
options: object;
editor: TuiEditor;
constructor(editorService: TuiService);
```

in the `/node_modules/ngx-tui-editor/tui-editor.component.d.ts` file.

What do I need to do here to satisfy this error? I have npm ied, npm updated, rebuilt, hard refreshed, restarted everything, and it just keeps coming up now.

*Edit*
Yes, the import statement for this is `import * as TuiEditor from 'tui-editor';` just grabbing everything. The index.d.ts file under tui-editor does have `declare namespace tuiEditor` with the brunt of the code it appears.
The interesting thing at the top of that file are two comments:

`// Type definitions for TOAST UI Editor v1.3.1`

`// TypeScript Version: 3.2.2`

I believe we are on TypeScript 3.9.2, but I dont know if that is where the issue lies.

Comment: can you locate the definition of the TuiEditor type and add it to the question?

Comment: @jahller I just added an edit. Does that help at all by chance?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else getting this issue, we were able to eliminate this error by declaring `editor: TuiEditor.default` as type. I submitted a PR to package creator.